# Does System.IO.Path class on Mono handles long path?

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I am working on File System related things where I want to test my code on Linux too. I am aware that System.IO.Path on windows can not handle the path if it is greater than MAX_PATH, is this restriction is same on Mono implementation of System.IO.Path? what is alternative on this?

Thanks,
Omky

Comment: Is that very hard to test yourself or hard to look into mono `Path` class source?

Comment: _"what is alternative on this?"_ - staying within the max path limits?

Comment: what is MAX_PATH? can you link to the docs about this?